# RxJava Observable subscription must be used

Tags: android, rx-java2

In RxJava 2 subscribe block is giving warning when after subscribing disposable is not used.
Example in Kotlin:

```
button.clicks().subscribe(...)
```

It is useful for asynchronous stuff or something that needs to be garbage collected in subscribe blocks, but in many cases it is just plain button click -> navigation stuff.

**Question 1**
Is it safe to NOT dispose pure view events, because it will get garbage collected with Activity itself or should I explicitly dispose of it, like

```
button.clicks().subscribe({startActivity(...)})
```

**Question 2**
What to do with those warnings? Let them be? Dispose just for the sake of getting rid of warnings?

Comment: You can suppress them, but in something like an `Activity` that has a lifecycle, I'd capture the `Disposable` and dispose it in `onDestroy`, `onPause` etc.

Comment: Yes, I can dispose, but why? It is not a good practice to do something just to get rid of warning. On the other hand, suppressing it would cover up useful cases

Comment: *It is not a good practice to do something just to get rid of warning* - by that logic, all warnings should never be fixed

Comment: @TimCastelijns I disagree. You fix warning to solve issue (null check, disposing network request), but not to get rid of yellow warning

Comment: Those are your options - leave the warning, suppress it (I think you want either 
 `@SuppressLint("CheckResult")` or `@SuppressWarnings("ResultOfMethodCallIgnored")` at the method call site), or use the returned `Disposable`. As you point out, calling `dispose()` isn't strictly necessary, but you could activate and terminate your subscription in `onResume/onPause`, because it shouldn't be possible to click buttons outside of those lifecycles anyway. It makes your intention a little clearer to future readers.